# Unable to select object not part of the initial DOM

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

I have a piece of HTML inserted dinamically with jQuery, by using the `.html()` method when user clicks on `'.acceptExtra'`:

HTML:

```
<div class="tripleButtonsWrap">
   <div class="tripleButtonsC">
        <div class="acceptExtra">
        ............
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.acceptExtra', function(){
            closeExtras();
    });

function closeExtras(){            
    $(document).find('.tripleButtonsC').fadeOut(400,function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('.tripleButtonsWrap').html(initialCode); //HTML PIECE INSERTED
        $(document).find('.tripleButtonsC').fadeIn(600);   
    }); 
}
```

The `initialCode` variable stores the HTML containing the '.acceptExtra' button, and as it is called by a delegate (`on('click','.acceptExtra', function()...`) it works properly again and again.

But the `'.tripleButtonsC'` only fades out the first time `closeExtras()` is executed. Next times it is not recognised by jQuery and so the entire `closeExtras()` function does nos apply.

I have tried selecting it by using the `$(document).find('.tripleButtonsC')...` with no positive result.

How can I make it being selected again by jQuery?

Comment: As a side node just event handlers require delegation using `$(document) ` finding does not. Just  use `$('.tripleButtonsC')`. Also it would be great of you reproduce your issue in a code snippet or a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: In your code `$(this).remove();` this can remove your `tripleButtonsC` class element so second time its not fadeout.

Comment: @ShaunakD that was my first try: $('.tripleButtonsC').fadeOut(400,function(){... I have re-tried with no possitive resul. $('.tripleButtonsC) is no longer recognised

Comment: @AkashChavda I know. I am looking forward to solve this.

Comment: Seems to work for me here: http://codepen.io/wallek876/pen/YXXjOJ

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try show hide concept.

Comment: @wallek876 oh.... I am reviewing all other code and I cant find the reason why does not work for me...

Comment: Make a Jsfiddle/codepen with the whole code if possible. The current code seems to be working.

Comment: Done! Check how '.cancelExtra' does not work (it is the same as acceptExtra but the only one works in here, sorry about the mess...) https://jsfiddle.net/8pp14hyt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is why it is not working:
Just before executing the function you have this dom:

```
<div class="tripleButtonsWrap">
   <div class="tripleButtonsC">
        <div class="acceptExtra">
        ............
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But after executing the `closeExtras` function ( `('.tripleButtonsWrap').html(initialCode);` )  you will have this dom:

```
<div class="tripleButtonsWrap">
     <div class="acceptExtra">
        ............
      </div>
</div>
```

Because the `initialCode` variable does not contain the div with class `tripleButtonsC`.

To make sure the div with class `tripleButtonsC` is not there inspect your html using google developer tool.

Comment: BINGO. There's no '.tripleButtonsC' div anymore. I missed that. I am about to try but for sure this is the problem. Very grateful, I'll tick if OK.

Comment: solved: initialCode="<div class='tripleButtonsC'>"+$('.tripleButtonsC').html()+"</div>";